# Rails: Getting all has_many objects associated with an active relation of parents

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, has-many, active-relation

I have what I suspect is a basic question. In my `rails` app, One `user` has many `scores`. Is there a way to get all the scores of an active relation of users. I can do user.scores (obviously) but if users is a group of users I need to do something like `users.scores`. This is clearly not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
Score.where(user: users)
```

This will construct sql like

```
select * from scores where user_id in (select *.id from users where ..)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following?

```
@users.collect(&:scores).flatten!
```

Comment: I think the accepted answer is more efficient. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Both will produce the same underlying `sql`. Which one to use depends upon your scenario and other context. Either way, I would move this logic to the model for testability and maintenance.

Comment: You are not right @Dharam, your code produces N+1 queries. But it could be improved using `includes`: `@users.includes(:scores).collect(&:scores).flatten!` - this will be only 2 queries.

Comment: Good call @MikDiet, didn't realize that.